# Actions not triggered with Paho MQTT and Threads

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am having problems getting my callback functons to trigger. I am using Paho-MQTT and initiating it using python threads.

```
class AquariumMonitor():


    def __init__(self):

        self.mClient = mqtt.Client(client_id="AQMonitor",clean_session=True, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31)
        self.mClient.connected_flag=False 
        self.mClient.on_message = self.incoming_message_processing
        self.mClient.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.mClient.on_publish = self.on_publish

        self.mClient.connect_async(broker_address)

        self.mClient.subscribe("AQ/#")

        # receive loop is defined in the base class
        self.mClient.loop_forever()
        print("closing")

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc==0:
            self.mClient.connected_flag=True #set flag
            print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
        else:
            print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)
def aq_monitor(appController):

    my_aq_monitor = AquariumMonitor()

if __name__ == '__main__':

IO_thread = Thread(target = aq_monitor, args=[appController])
```

It appears that none of my callbacks are triggered

Comment: You have not started the thread

Answer (score 0):

the thread has been created but not started. Use `IO_thread.start()` to start the thread.

There is a potential improvement on 'subscribing topics':

Usually we do that `self.mClient.subscribe("AQ/#")` inside `on_connect` callback. `connect_async` 'queues' a connect task that won't be executed until your `loop_forever`. If you subscribe right after connect_async, you will get a MQTT_ERR_NO_CONN.

Most client functions returns error values(for instance `MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS` and `MQTT_ERR_NO_CONN`). You'd better handle the return values.